# Something causing interference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tumblr

So I've got the following code that works in jsfiddle, but not on the actual website, which leads me to believe that the only way I'm going to get it working is for someone with more experience than I to look through the source and see what's interfering.

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var $elements = $('body').children('div[class^=class]').on('click', function () {
        $elements.removeClass('classname')
                 .not('.' + this.className)
                 .addClass('classname');
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Website: http://sinfulgurotesque.tumblr.com/recs

Edit: I've removed a section of code from the website that had nothing to do with this part. (It was the deprecated code, and it didn't offer much in terms of functionality anyways.)

Comment: And, those deprecated functions have NOTHING to do with the code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You're using jQuery 1.10.1 in your page, and the error you're getting:

> jquery.style-my-tooltips.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a
>   function

is referring to the `.live()` function used by the plugin which was removed in jQuery 1.9

```
$(".smt-current-element").live("mouseout mousedown click",function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling depracated JS functions. I got:

> TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

when opening your page. Try changing `.live()` to `.on()`

Like so

`$("body").on("mouseout mousedown click", ".smt-current-element", function(){...`

Comment: You can't directly change `.live()` to `.on()`.  You have to change the structure of the arguments when doing so because `.on()` takes different arguments.